# MySQL Union not showing 2nd query result set

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.6, union, subtypes

I am doing a union of 2 queries and trying to fetch data on two different columns, however the union is not fetching the value from 2nd result set. Can you please guide me on this.

```
select  *
    From  
      ( SELECT  c1.ia_device_home_carrier, avg(rf1.ia_signal_strengh_rssi) as ss
            from  rf_voice_data_verizon_sec2 rf1, device_market_config d1,
                ia_device_carrier c1
            where  rf1.ia_device_id = d1.ia_device_id
              and  rf1.ia_device_id = c1.ia_device_id
              and  rf1.ia_signal_strengh_rssi BETWEEN -150.0 AND -40.0
              and  d1.ia_project_name = 'AA'
            group by  ia_device_home_carrier
         union 
         select  c2.ia_device_home_carrier, avg(rf2.httpul) as http
            from  rf_voice_data_verizon_sec2 rf2, device_market_config d2,
                ia_device_carrier c2
            where  rf2.ia_device_id = d2.ia_device_id
              and  rf2.ia_device_id = c2.ia_device_id
              and  rf2.httpul > 0
              and  d2.ia_project_name = 'AA'
            group by  ia_device_home_carrier 
      ) x
    group by  ia_device_home_carrier

                            +------------------------+----------+
                            | ia_device_home_carrier | ss       |
                            +------------------------+----------+
                            | xyz                    | -77.8559 |
                            | abcggg                 | -69.8158 |
                            | sfg                    | -95.8884 |
                            | VZW                    | -94.3992 |
                            +------------------------+----------+
```

But i need a result set like this

```
                            +------------------------+----------+------------+
                            | ia_device_home_carrier | ss       |   httpul   |
                            +------------------------+----------+------------+
                            | xyz                    | -77.8559 |  7848.5175 |
                            | abcggg                 | -69.8158 |  5623.5231 |
                            | sfg                    | -95.8884 |  7228.5677 |
                            | VZW                    | -94.3992 |  7118.3175 |
                            +------------------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Union adds rows, not columns, you probably want a join instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since `UNION` lines up the columns, not the column names, you cannot directly go from what you have.  However, here is one technique:

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT x, ss     FROM...
    UNION
    SELECT x, httpul FROM...
)
```

do

```
SELECT  x,
        MAX(ss) AS ss,  -- MAX() will ignore the NULL from the 'other' table
        MAX(httpul) AS httpul
FROM (
    SELECT x,         ss, NULL AS httpul  FROM ...
    UNION
    SELECT x, NULL AS ss,         httpul  FROM ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  SS.IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER ,SS.SS ,HTTP.HTTP
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  C1.IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER, AVG(RF1.IA_SIGNAL_STRENGH_RSSI) AS SS
            FROM  RF_VOICE_DATA_VERIZON_SEC2 RF1, DEVICE_MARKET_CONFIG D1,
                IA_DEVICE_CARRIER C1
            WHERE  RF1.IA_DEVICE_ID = D1.IA_DEVICE_ID
              AND  RF1.IA_DEVICE_ID = C1.IA_DEVICE_ID
              AND  RF1.IA_SIGNAL_STRENGH_RSSI BETWEEN -150.0 AND -40.0
              AND  D1.IA_PROJECT_NAME = 'AA'
            GROUP BY  IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER
      ) SS
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  C2.IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER, AVG(RF2.HTTPUL) AS HTTP
            FROM  RF_VOICE_DATA_VERIZON_SEC2 RF2, DEVICE_MARKET_CONFIG D2,
                IA_DEVICE_CARRIER C2
            WHERE  RF2.IA_DEVICE_ID = D2.IA_DEVICE_ID
              AND  RF2.IA_DEVICE_ID = C2.IA_DEVICE_ID
              AND  RF2.HTTPUL > 0
              AND  D2.IA_PROJECT_NAME = 'AA'
            GROUP BY  IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER
      ) HTTP ON SS.IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER=HTTP.IA_DEVICE_HOME_CARRIER
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try with a join, but forgot to put the ON Clause at the end. Any ways thanks